# Bitbucket Pipeline build never ends

Tags: python-3.x, shell, bitbucket, digital-ocean

This is essentially the same issue as [this individual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65764120/bitbucket-pipeline-ssh-doesnt-end)

I have a bitbucket pipeline file `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` which executes the file `deploy.sh` when a new commit is made to the `main` branch. `deploy.sh` in turn calls `pull.sh` which performs a set of actions:

1. If it exists, kill the existing `refgator-api.py` process
2. Change to the directory containing the repo
3. Pull from the repo
4. Change to the directory containing `refgator-api.py`
5. Execute `python3 refgator-api.py`

It's at this last step that my bitbucket pipeline will continue executing (consuming all my build minutes).

Is there any way I can complete the bitbucket pipeline successfully after `pull.sh` has performed `python3 refgator-api.py`?

### bitbucket-ipelines.yml

```
image: atlassian/default-image:latest

pipelines:
    default:
      - step:
          script:
              - cat ./deploy.sh | ssh -tt root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
              - echo "Deploy step finished"
```

### deploy.sh

```
echo "Deploy Script Started"
cd
sh pull.sh
echo "Deploy script finished execution"
```

### pull.sh

```
## Kills the current process which is restarted later
kill -9 $(pgrep -f refgator-api.py)

## And change to directory containing the repo
cd eg-api

## Pull from the repo
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v" git pull git@bitbucket.org:myusername/myrepo.git

## Change to directory containing the python file to execute
cd refgator-api
python3 refgator-api.py &
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key issue here was the attempt at getting the python script `refgator-api.py` up and running and closing off the session.

This doesn't seem to be possible using a shell script directly. However, it is possible to use `supervisor` on the remote server.

In this case I installed supervisor `apt-get install supervisor` and did the following:

### bitbucket pipelines

```
image: atlassian/default-image:latest

pipelines:
    default:
      - step:
          script:
              - cat ./deploy.sh | ssh -tt root@143.198.164.197
              - echo "DEPLOY STEP FINISHED"
```

### Deploy.sh

```
printf "=== Deploy Script Started ===\n"
printf "Stop all supervisorctl processes\n"
supervisorctl stop all

sh refgator-pull.sh

printf "Start all supervisorctl processes\n"
supervisorctl start all
exit
```

### Pull.sh

```
printf "==== Repo Pull ====\n"
printf "Attempting pull from repo\n"
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh " git pull git@bitbucket.org:myusername/myrepo.git
printf "Repo: Local Copy Updated\n"
```

Comment: For later reference this same issue can also be caused by the key on the server being generated _with_ a passphrase. Bitbucket will always stall when a passphrase is requested and it can't provide it. The fix for this is to generate a key without a passphrase.